# Is it always possible to retrieve data from a rewritable CD? And using partitioning and formatting discuss their forensic implications

Tags: forensics

Is it possible to retrieve data from a rewritable CD?
Using partitioning and formatting discuss their forensic implications.

Comment: you mean data that has been overwritten ? As for the second part of your question I don't understand. a cd/dvd has no partition, it's an iso, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image

Comment: If you want to destroy the information on any optical disk, the only reasonable way to do so is to destroy the disk itself.